# Pandas slicing on a timeseries seems inconsistent with list slicing

Tags: python, pandas, slice

```
times = [datetime(2011, 01, 03, 0, 10 + i, 0) for i in range(5)]
series = pd.TimeSeries(range(5), index=times)
series.ix[datetime(2011, 01, 03, 0, 10, 0):datetime(2011, 01, 03, 0, 13, 0)]

2011-01-03 00:10:00    0
2011-01-03 00:11:00    1
2011-01-03 00:12:00    2
2011-01-03 00:13:00    3
```

but

```
x = range(5)
x[0:3]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Also,

```
times = [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(1000000 - 1)]
df = pd.TimeSeries(range(1000000 - 1), times)
len(df.ix[datetime.datetime(1900,1,1):datetime.datetime(2100,1,1)])

999999
```

But

```
times = [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(1000000)]
df = pd.TimeSeries(range(1000000), times)
len(df.ix[datetime.datetime(1900,1,1):datetime.datetime(2100,1,1)])
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> ```
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
>     # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 35, in __getitem__
>     return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 234, in _getitem_axis
>     return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 460, in _get_slice_axis
>     i, j = labels.slice_locs(start, stop)
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.py", line 949, in slice_locs
>     return Index.slice_locs(self, start, end)
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1057, in slice_locs
>     end_slice = self.get_loc(end) + 1
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.py", line 919, in get_loc
>     return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd", line 378, in pandas.lib.DatetimeEngine.get_loc (pandas\src\tseries.c:108808)
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd", line 390, in pandas.lib.DatetimeEngine.get_loc (pandas\src\tseries.c:108422)
>   File "C:\dev\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd", line 32, in util.get_value_at (pandas\src\tseries.c:112091)
> IndexError: index out of bounds
> ```

Comment: I've created an issue referencing the last item (which is a bug): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1562

Comment: The bug's been fixed in git master, will be in the upcoming 0.8.1 release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-labels):

*Slicing with labels is semantically slightly different because the slice start and stop are **inclusive** in the label-based case*